# Are the output values of the random forest model acceptable?

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a random forest model to predict the sales prices of houses. The output of the model after tuning it is as follows:

```
> print(rf1)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = price ~ ., data = train, mtry = 5, ntree = 300,      importance = T, proximity = T, do.trace = T) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 300
No. of variables tried at each split: 5

          Mean of squared residuals: 34804126985
                    % Var explained: 73.67
> cor(p2, test$price)
[1] 0.8523592
> caret::RMSE(p2, test$price)
[1] 197536.8
> mean(rf1$mse)
[1] 36350888740
```

I want to know if the values of mse and rmse are acceptable since what I have generally known is that lesser the values, the better. But, in this case, the values are much higher. Also, R^2 value os 0.7367 which is quite good. Does calculating the accuracy of 0.8523592 makes sense in case of regression?

The code after tuning the 1st random forest model is as follows:

```
# tuning the rf model
t <- tuneRF(train[, -1], train[, 1],
            ntreeTry = 300,
            plot = T,
            stepFactor = 0.5,
            trace = T)
?tuneRF

# rf model again
rf1 <- randomForest(price ~ ., data = train, mtry = 5, ntree = 300, importance = T,
                    proximity = T, do.trace = T)
```

Also, there is not much improvement in the tuned model from the 1st model.

Comment: First : Your data is obviously not normalised (gaussian, 0-1, ...), this can be tricky since variable with higher variance will "weight" more at splitting node.

Your RMSE of ~2e5 can be compared with test$price. How distant is your average prediction, 10%, 50% of the target ? You could plot the residuals to find regions not well predicted.
You can also calculate manually adjusted r2 (keeps you from overestimating your model with too many predictors), rmse, mae, max error to help you decide if your model is good enough.

Comment: For normalization, I read somewhere that it is not needed for the random forest model because the answer before and after does not change. Also, if I go ahead with normalization, I would need to normalize all the variables including the 'price' variable, right? And, I would need them to be on one scale - like from 0 to 1 for all of them, right?

Comment: After some tests and looking at the doc : [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) ; Indeed normalization is not mentionned as mandatory.
It is worth comparing both approach some times. And yes if you do normalize your data, normalize all inputs using **scale** or any custom function.